# Error in createDataPartition.... : y must have at least 2 data points

Tags: r

i need help with createDataPartition
I am getting this error

> Error in createDataPartition(TBdta$medv, p = 0.8, list = FALSE) : y must have at least 2 data points

my code

```
library(tibble)
dta <- url("http://course1.winona.edu/bdeppa/Stat%20425/Data/Boston_Housing.csv")
TBdta <- as_tibble(read.csv(dta, check.names = FALSE)) 
TBdta
```

My error comes when i run the below chunch

```
# Split out validation dataset
# create a list of 80% of the rows in the original dataset we can use for training
set.seed(7)
validationIndex <- createDataPartition(TBdta$medv, p=0.80, list=FALSE)
# select 20% of the data for validation
validation <- TBdta$medv[-validationIndex,]
# use the remaining 80% of data to training and testing the models
dataset <- TBdta$medv[validationIndex,]
```

> Error in createDataPartition(TBdta$medv, p = 0.8, list = FALSE) : y must have at least 2 data points

Comment: I'm afraid that is just a typo. The column name is `MEDV` and you are using `medv` in lower case.

Comment: thank you but that doesn't work either, still get Warning messages:
1: Unknown or uninitialised column: 'medv'. 
2: Unknown or uninitialised column: 'medv'. 
Unknown or uninitialised column: 'medv'.Unknown or uninitialised column: 'medv'.

Comment: are you sure you are using the correct column name? It works for me though. `validationIndex <- caret::createDataPartition(TBdta$MEDV, p=0.80, list=FALSE)`

Comment: this is my code set.seed(7)
validationIndex <- caret::createDataPartition(TBdta$MEDV, p=0.80, list=FALSE)
# select 20% of the data for validation
validation <- TBdta$MEDV[-validationIndex,]
# use the remaining 80% of data to training and testing the models
dataset <- TBdta$MEDV[validationIndex,]

Comment: still get error, Show in New WindowClear OutputExpand/Collapse Output
Warning messages:
1: Unknown or uninitialised column: 'medv'. 
2: Unknown or uninitialised column: 'medv'. 
3: Unknown or uninitialised column: 'medv'. 
Error in TBdta$MEDV[-validationIndex, ] : incorrect number of dimensions

Comment: code error at  validation <- TBdta$MEDV[-validationIndex,]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess what you need is

```
set.seed(7)
validationIndex <- caret::createDataPartition(TBdta$MEDV, p=0.80, list=FALSE)
validation <- TBdta[-validationIndex,]
dataset <- TBdta[validationIndex,]
```

So that you have

```
dim(validation)
#[1] 99 14
dim(dataset)
#[1] 407  14
```

Comment: Fantastic and that works. Kudos Ronak